# Use php to post blogpost

Tags: php, include

The problem is this: I have a site called http://legacybydesign.tv/ and I have written everything myself. Problem is that everytime I post a new blogpost I need to change many things on the page and it can take up to 20 min to do that.

So I want to solve this problem by using php.
I know you can use `<?php include("blogpost_001.php") ?>`.

Problem is that I need to change things in the meta data and in the footer. So I want just be able to create a file.php and in the file have a sturuture that look like this:

title: (include in `<title></title>` and og:title)

description: (include in meta description and og:description)

Blog title: (include in h1)

time: (include in p under title)

Content...

quote footer: (include in the share section at bottom)

And last, question at the end: (include in the question area)

Here is link to a blogpost where you can see all the stuff in action.

http://legacybydesign.tv/2013/hope-on-mission.html

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you already written any PHP for the blog or is this totally from scratch (except for the static content) ?

Comment: For clarification, do you have an interest in learning PHP, to the stage of being able to make a functioning blog, or do you just want any way of easily updating your blog? Because if you just need a way to edit it, then you should be using an existing CMS rather than writing the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just post occasionally, or if you don't want to spend a long amount of time on PHP for this, I recommend you use tools that were made explicitly for this purpose, such as WordPress.

You can reinvent the wheel if you want and do everything from scratch, but be aware that this will require more work than having to modify the HTML directly, especially if you don't write many articles, which seems to be your case.

Look up WordPress and other CMS options.

In short, it's only worth it if you're really interested in learning PHP, if you're not interested, it's not worth doing it yourself.